# Targeting odd even style to specific table with id

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a few tables  of which I would only like to target the even and odd rows:

```
<table class="record">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Score</th>
    <th scope="col">Time</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1.20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>1.35</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>1.39</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to use the following code which I found online, but it works but on all of the tables around the site:

```css
tr:nth-child(even) { background: #666; }
tr:nth-child(odd)  { background: #CCC; }
```

Any suggestions how can I target on tables only with a class of "record" ?
Thank you for your suggestions.

Edit:
And what if this tables is under another table as td? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First things first: your question title implies/states that you want to use an `id`, whereas in your question-code you're using a `class`, to select the relevant `table` element. These are *not* equivalent; an element may have only one `id`, but multiple classes. That said, to *use* a class, the posted answer has you covered.

If, on the other hand, you want to use an `id` (as stated in your title), then replace `.record` with `#idOfTable` (and remember to pass an `id` to your HTML: `<table id="idOfTable"><!-- other stuff --></table>`).

You can, of course, combine an `id` with a `class` selector:

Just pass the ancestor as part of the selector:

```
.record tr:nth-child(even) {background: #666;}
.record tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #CCC;}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J5x7A/).

On the grounds you may only want this to work within the `tbody`, you can also pass that as part of the selector:

```
.record tbody tr:nth-child(even) {background: #666;}
.record tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #CCC;}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J5x7A/1/).

You can, of course, combine an `id` with a `class` selector:

```
#idOfTable.classNameOfTable {
    /* CSS */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add `table.record` before the CSS code you posted like so:

```css
table.record tr:nth-child(even) { background: #666; }
table.record tr:nth-child(odd)  { background: #CCC; }
```

The `table` part is to delimit this only to tables as there might be other elements with the class `record` and you don't this to interfere with them.

The `.record` just specifies the class (`<elem>.<class>` is the syntax and `<elem>` is not necessary).

And the nesting is simple to understand too: it looks for matching elements within the outer elements. [Here is the relevant W3S documentation.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grouping_nesting.asp)

Comment: **FGITW lives on!** (Fastest Gun in the West)

Comment: Perhaps this is somehow subjective to each users' machine, but if you hover over the '**mins ago**' text (to see the tooltips), it looks like you were actually second.

Comment: @DavidThomas What? No fair. The other guy posted his answer while I was editing. Actually, I'd got stuck at the captcha screen and b'coz I was in such a hurry, I got it wrong and had to repeat it 2 times before my answer was allowed to be posted.

Comment: Um, I *am* the other guy. If you think there's a problem with how this has fallen out, then by all means post a question to [meta] (though I'd suggest searching for previous similar questions first), and see if there's any way that the mods or devs can help you?

Comment: I just realized you were the other answerer. But anyway. I'm happy I got 500 rep. You've got a 50k. 5-digit reps are cool. While [it might not get me a job](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/20407/will-high-reputation-in-stack-overflow-help-to-get-a-good-job), it still is pretty cool. and since I'm 13, I already have _waay_ too much time on my hands. Any tips on how to get there? Also, please check out [ma blog](http://yatharthrock.blogspot.com)!

Comment: @DavidThomas Again. See what I mean? While I was posting my answer and finding that link (it's bookmarked in my [Programmers Account](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/50954/yatharthrock)), you posted a comment, caused by a misunderstanding that my comment could've resolved had it been posted earlier.

Comment: And I don't mind too much. What's 10 rep between fellow StackExchangers (that _is_ the demonym for StackExchange, yes?) **:)**

Comment: It could be; it seems valid. Any tips on..? How to get to high rep: (persevere, and keep posting quality answers that others find useful), for getting a job? Dunno, personally I work in healthcare (as an [ODP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_Department_Practitioners)), Stack Overflow's mostly for fun (though I'd happily take a front-end web-dev job!). Just use your time wisely; and remember to get outside and have a life, don't *just* loiter on SO =)

Comment: @DavidThomas I think I better move this discussion to chat, the intent of continuing the discussion lies with you btu atleast it'll make the comments on the post less diluted...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17353/discussion-between-yatharthrock-and-david-thomas)